# Powershell "one liner" for Get-Content and Beep in the console

Tags: command-line, powershell

I love the command Get-Content, especially with the **-tai**l and **-wait** parameters...

But, I'd love it even more if I could write a 'one-liner' to have it use Beep whenever a new entry shows up.

I've tried using pipes and 'foreach' but can't seem to find the right combination.  I don't want to write a multiline script.  But for each new line that appears - beep.

```
"[console]::beep(500,300)"

"Get-Content '\\server\share\file.txt' -tail 10 -wait"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You want an audible tone when a new file or folder is found in a given network share? Is that correct?

Comment: No, just for each new line.  Each new character would be too much.  But, If I update the file with new entries line by line - a single be ideal.

Comment: `Get-Content D:\01temp\file.txt -Tail 10 -Wait | foreach { $_,[console]::beep(500,300) }` this works, but youll get 2 beeps each time you hit save in the txt file.

Comment: @Narzard, I think that's the case.  I wasn't familiar with the '$_' variable case.  It's just accepting the input from Get-Content, correct?  I was using the wrong operator as well  '>' instead of '|' to pipe it.

Comment: Why a one-liner? As a best practice. It is generally, well, almost always stated that OL's, using aliases, etc., are great for ad-hoc, throwaway code, but not in production/shared scripts. With what ' @Narzard ', it will beep on any add/line change/save and multiple times for such action. Still, a good simple one-liner, if you don't mind the extraneous beeps.

Comment: @postanote  Its just preference for me.  I don't have a massive library of scripts, but I do like to monitor a few files that get updated in various places.  It helps to set up a quick way to monitor with audio and hear when one of the files is updated.  Also, I can change the console::beep for different files.  neat huh?  (easy to memorize too)

Thanks @Narzard!

Comment: Understood. Many are in a similar mindset. I use one-liners daily, and lot's of aliases when I do, but not in my Source Repor's / Production scripts and the like. All my production code has aliases for them just for that reason. One can do multiline code in the console as well, though it's a bit more cumbersome than in the ISE/VSCode, et all.

Answer (score 1):

This will only check line count and beep only when the line count is incremented.

```
$LineCount = 0
Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\BeepOnAddLine.txt' -tail 10 -wait | 
ForEach-Object{
    If ($LineCount -lt [Linq.Enumerable]::Count([System.IO.File]::ReadLines('D:\Temp\BeepOnAddLine.txt')))
    {
        [console]::beep(500,300)
        $LineCount = [Linq.Enumerable]::Count([System.IO.File]::ReadLines('D:\Temp\BeepOnAddLine.txt'))
    }
}
```

Of course, you can put this all on one-liner using semi-colons, but as we know that is not a true one-liner. There are hard to read, debug, etc.

```
$LineCount = 0;Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\BeepOnAddLine.txt' -tail 10 -wait | ForEach-Object{If ($LineCount -lt [Linq.Enumerable]::Count([System.IO.File]::ReadLines('D:\Temp\BeepOnAddLine.txt'))) {[console]::beep(500,300);$LineCount = [Linq.Enumerable]::Count([System.IO.File]::ReadLines('D:\Temp\BeepOnAddLine.txt'))}}


# A bit shorter using aliases and no .Net namespace, but well, you know.
$FP='D:\Temp\BeepOnAddLine.txt';$LC=0;gc $FP -tail 10 -wait|%{If ($LC -lt (gc $FP|measure -Line).Lines){[console]::beep(500,300);$LC=(gc $FP|measure -Line).Lines}}
```

Comment: This is very formal and definitely does the trick.  Nice work.  Bit long for me, but a very straight forward method.  Thanks!

Comment: No worries, glad it gave you something to look at differently. Yet, you can just make it a  script, and call directly in the console ***.\MonitorMyFile.ps1*** or some FQDN to the script repo, vs typing stuff out all the time. You put that library of scripts on a central share and run as normal.